# On iOS, is there a way to force the creation of UITableViewCell if the table only has 20 or 25 rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

**The Short question is:** can we force the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called for "non-displayed cells" (say, cell 8 to 25), so that we pre-fetch images from server and never reuse cells if the table merely has 20 or 25 rows?

---

**Details:** I think the mechanism of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is mainly to preserve memory, especially on the iPhone or iPod Touch, so that if a table has 1000 rows, there won't be 1000 `UITableViewCell` objects (`UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView`), which will use a lot of memory, but only 10 objects or so, and these objects can be "reused", so memory use can be kept to a small size.

But what if each row has an image fetched on the server?  Instead of building a separate image cache with a separate thread, can we let `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` fetch the first 7 images and display the table, and later on, force cell 8 to 25 to be rendered, and never call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` (so we have 25 of such `UITableViewCell` objects and do not reuse them).  How can that be done and is it actually a practical and simple solution?

Answer (score 6):

Caching images hardly belongs in the view layer; neither does the retrieval of these images from the server.

You should take the approach that you describe in your post - caching the images separately from the table, and then retrieve these images from that image cache.

You can build an `ImageProvider` class that gives you an image based on its key, and use that provider in constructing the table cells. In turn, the `ImageProvider` decides on whether to load the images from the server or to load them from cache, hiding the details from the table view.

This approach gives you significant amount of flexibility: should you decide to save on the network traffic by caching the images locally on the device, the approach with a separate cache lets you do that without disturbing the view layer. It also lets you save memory by flushing the cached images to temp files, for example, on receiving a low memory warning.

Comment: what if when the cell renders the image, the image is not in the `ImageProvider` yet?  Will it "block" and wait for the image (wait for image from the net server), or will it show nothing?  If blocking is not desired, then showing nothing will require some mechanism to populate that image once it is fetched in `ImageProvider`?

Comment: @動靜能量 - If the image is not in ImageProvider, you can download/render it in a background thread and then update the cell when the image is available.  I'm sure I've seen examples either in CS193P on iTunesU or in the WWDC videos.

Comment: I see... so let a background thread render it so that even if that thread is blocking, it is ok...

Comment: @動靜能量 You can get fancy, and make the image provider call you back with an image if it is not available, passing a completion block to call your cell back when the download has completed. If you go that route, through, be prepared to implement `prepareForReuse` in your cell so that you could cancel the callback if the cell scrolls off the view before the image download is complete.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if there can be a `UIDeferredImageView` or `UICachedImageView`, maybe that can suit the purpose?  So this class is subclassed from `UIImageView` and it fetches image from the server, like a web browser does, and it has a cache to cache the `CGImage` or `UIImage`, so we don't have to implement the browser behavior every time?  Do you think this is good way to do it?

Comment: @動靜能量 The problem with this approach is that the caching will be on the view side. So if a deferred / cached image viewer is embedded in a table cell and then gets reused, the data cached inside the special viewer will be lost. The caching should happen in a single place accessible from multiple table cells.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Or what if the `UICachedImageView` has a singleton cache which is unique and common to the whole app?

Comment: @動靜能量 Although it is not necessary that the cache is owned by `UICachedImageView` -- it could be external to it for all objects, not only `UICachedImageView` to use as necessary, -- your solution with a singleton cache is definitely valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the `UITableView` to call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The workaround I can think of is to create `UITableViewCell` instances in advance, store them in an `NSArray` and have `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` return the instance you have already created indexing the array of pre-created rows.

Comment: That was my first thought as well and I have seen people doing so. Personally however I have never seen a good reason to do that.

Comment: I have never seen a reason to do it either, but the asker seems to have a useful scenario for this.

Comment: aye, that seems to be the case :D

Comment: @Till you would do what dasblinkenlight suggested as well?

Comment: @(sry can not quote your name) yes, caching is a task that should be tagged onto the communication client for number of reasons - one being server-side ETAG caching.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a terrible idea, it is possible to do this by creating a UIScrollView as large as the table and then adding a UITableView with scrolling disabled to it.

```
CGSize tableSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);
UIScrollView* aScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableSize.width, tableSize.height)];

UITableView* aTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableSize.width, tableSize.height)];
aTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[aScrollView addSubview:aTableView];
[aTableView release];

[self.view addSubview:aScrollView];
[aScrollView release];
```

Comment: you mean, if the scrollView is created and then the table is added to it, the system will actually try to render all the rows?  (instead of only the one fit on screen)

Comment: Yes. Because from the UITableView's perspective, all rows __are__ on the screen.

Comment: why do you think getting all 25 images like that is not good?

Comment: It is not how UITableView is supposed to be used. The hassle of writing all of that code is much less than the hassle of simply writing an image caching class. Additionally, using a separate image cacher will reduce memory consumption, something which is very important on a limited platform like iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to prefetch all the images you need than loading all cells. I recommend using for this purpose [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It also includes an [image prefetcher](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImagePrefetcher.h), which you can use to load all the images before showing the UITableView contents.